# How do I troubleshoot the Groovy error "unable to resolve class spock.lang.Specification"?

Tags: groovy

I am using Ubuntu Linux 16, Gradle 2.10, Groovy 2.4.5, and Java Version 9.  I'd like to remove Gradle if I don't need it.  I am trying to run this program here from [GitHub](https://github.com/timezra/groovy-trampoline-memoize-specs/blob/master/src/test/groovy/timezra/groovy/trampoline_memoize/RecursiveMemoizationSpec.groovy).

Here is the text of the code:

```
package timezra.groovy.trampoline_memoize

import spock.lang.Specification

class RecursiveMemoizationSpec extends Specification {

    int count

    def fib = { n ->
        count++
        if(n == 0) 0
        else if(n == 1) 1
        else fib.call(n-1) + fib.call(n-2)
    }.memoize()

    def "calls should be cached"() {
        when:
        def actual = fib 10

        then:
        actual == 55
        count == 11
        // count == 177 //unmemoized
    }
}
```

When I run it with

> groovy RecursiveMemoizationSpec.groovy

I get this error:

> /groovy-trampoline-memoize-specs/src/test/groovy/timezra/groovy/trampoline_memoize/RecursiveMemoizationSpec.groovy:
>   3: unable to resolve class spock.lang.Specification  @ line 3, column
>   1.    import spock.lang.Specification    ^
>
> 1 error

This program was quoted on different websites.  Those versions produce the same problem.  I expected it to work without this error.  How do I get the program above to work?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old project and it doesn't look like it's been touched in 7 years. You shouldn't discard gradle but learn how to use it. checking out the build file you can see that it add the Groovy(1.8.3) and spoc dependencies. Since this project doesn't have a gradle wrapper I would use sdkman to download and install gradle:

https://sdkman.io/install

Then I would just run gradle test from the root of the project.

Another issue you might run into is that you are running Java 9. Groovy 1.8.3, probably won't run on Java 9. I know that Groovy has been working on groovy 9+ compatibility, in the 2.5.x version, and will be adding more syntax support in 3.0. So you can either update the build file to use a never version of Groovy, or downgrade to Java 8. If you install sdkman, it also, gives you an easy way to manage, and switch Java version on the fly.

If you still really want to get rid of gradle then you'll have to use the Groovy @Grab annotations, which will pull in the dependencies similar to gradle:

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html

But I would recommend that you get to know Gradle, because it is a powerful build system.